# Galatians 1:2 - Who are the brethren who were with Paul?

Tags: referent-identification, galatians

Galatians 1:1-2 says (KJV):

> 1 Paul, an apostle, (not of men, neither by man, but by Jesus Christ, and God the Father, who raised him from the dead;) ***and all the brethren which are with me***, unto the churches of Galatia:

Who are the brethren that were with Paul when he wrote this letter?  Did Paul just assume they would agree with the letter?  Or did they specifically read the letter and approve it? Would the Galatians have known them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at these verses in their context. The Εpistle to the Galatians begins as follows (as there are no serious textual or interpretational issues here I will cite only the KJV):

> 1 Paul, an apostle, (not of men, neither by man, but by Jesus Christ, and God the Father, who raised him from the dead;) 2 and all the brethren which are with me, unto the churches of Galatia: 3 grace be to you and peace from God the Father, and from our Lord Jesus Christ, 4 who gave himself for our sins, that he might deliver us from this present evil world, according to the will of God and our Father: 5 to whom be glory for ever and ever. Amen.

This is a closed formula, ending with “Amen”; in it Paul, together with “all the brethren which are with me”, send their salutations to the addressees. Of course, we do not know the names of these brethren.

In the next verse there is fresh start, in the first person singular (“I marvel”,  θαυμάζω). Here, and in the remainder of the epistle, Paul is speaking in his own name only. There is thus no need to assume that the "brethren" agreed with the letter, or had even read it. That is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably already consulted commentators on who these *brothers/brethren* may have been. If so, you likely realize your question is a difficult one to answer with any degree of certainty. Some commentators are not even sure if Paul was addressing churches in Northern or Southern Galatia, although the popular opinion seems to be he was addressing the Southern churches in cities such as Iconium, Lystra, Antioch, and Derbe (see Constable's Notes [here](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Galatians+1)).

> "'And all the brethren which are with me' - It was usual for Paul to associate with him the ministers of the gospel, or other Christians who were with him, in expressing friendly salutations to the churches to which he wrote, or as uniting with him, and concurring in the sentiments which he expressed. Though Paul claimed to be inspired, yet it would do much to conciliate favor for what he advanced, if others also concurred with what he said, and especially if they were known to the churches to which the epistles were written. Sometimes the names of others were associated with his in the Epistle; see the 1 Corinthians 1:1 note; Philippians 1:1 note; Colossians 1:1 note; 1 Thessalonians 1:1 note. Since we do not know where this epistle was written, of course we are ignorant who the "brethren" were, who are here referred to. They may have been ministers with Paul, or they may have been the private members of the churches. Commentators have been much divided in opinion on the subject; but all is conjecture. It is obviously impossible to determine" (Barnes' notes quoted [here](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/galatians/1-2.htm)).

We do know, of course, that Paul had travelling companions on his missionary journeys, during which he had the privilege of planting churches and, at times, staying put until a given church's gestation, birth, and toddler stage were complete (see, for example, Acts 18, especially vvv.9-11). Among his Christian companions were Dr. Luke, Silas, Timothy, Titus, John-Mark, and Barnabus; for others, see the list [here](http://www.christianshepherd.org/meditations/doctrinal_meditations/companions_of_paul.pdf)).

What I have said thus far could be investigated further, in Berean-believer fashion (see Acts 17:11), and that very investigation in itself could turn out to be a blessing. Moreover, some day (if not already) an archeologist will uncover the very information you are seeking, perhaps in a surviving manuscript of a non-canonical letter from the first or second century A.D.

In conclusion, had God wanted us to know exactly who was with Paul when he wrote his Galatian letter, God would have let us know. As it is, however, there are any number of men (and women, too) who could reasonably be put on a short list of possible companions.

Best wishes in your explorations.